# PHP Header Redirect Not working on site, have researched, still need assistance

Tags: php, redirect, header, warnings

```
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
if($_POST['linklabel'] == '')
{
    header('Location: index.php?VIEW=BLAH&message=failure');
}
else
{
```

Here is my code, it is giving me the typical redirect error of :
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/74/8256574/blah/blah/index.php:24) in /home/content/74/8256574/blah/blah/blah/blah.php on line 14.

The header redirect above is what is on line 14.  On line 24 of the index.php page, there is a css file (don't think that would be causing the issue..).

I am submitting a form, and checking the form for empty values.  If it finds an empty value, redirect to above URL with &message=failure

I know there are a lot of questions on here asking the same thing but I still can't solve my issue.  Please, any help would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of duplicates, if I need to I will remove this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If data has been sent to the browser, you can not modify header info. Simple fix is to buffer the output.

```
ob_start(); // Put at the top of your script.
header('Location: index.php?VIEW=BLAH&message=failure');
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Always the simple crap haha.  Is this a valid fix though, or just a bandaid?

Comment: @K_G It's a bandaid, the real solution is to make sure your check is done BEFORE the output is started.

Comment: Just let's pretend there is nothing going on... I would call this suppressing stuff rather than fixing the actual problem.

Comment: Let's just say the `ob_*` methods exist for a reason, and using them in this snippet is practical. If you find yourself using them all the time and losing track of them, then a logical refactor is the way to go.

Comment: @sg3s That's easy for you to say as a "real solution", but what if he is working on a single file in a large framework with a team of 20 devs in 3 countries and he doesn't have access to common code or shared headers/footers/etc. Then your suggestion costs the company $15,000 in a week long refactor effort + QA, whereas AlienWebguy's suggestion is a more isolated fix and would take one dev a few minutes to implement and test. "Fix and revisit", don't "Refactor from a soap box".

Comment: Thanks for the support @PHPBree, but my solution was just meant for a small script. I've worked on large multi-national teams where devs sneak in hacks at 3am and the framework turns to spaghetti, and then the company ends up doing a $150,000 refactor effort to overhaul the code base. Both of you have good points but it's not so cut and dry. A little snippet on SO though, ob_start() works just fine :)

Comment: @PHPBree that's a moot argument, in the real world with a team of 20 devs in multiple countries an application has a proper MVC setup since you really can't do without when working in a team that large, and with 20 **professionals** you will not have this problem since they should all get what they're doing, if not someone who does will end up correcting this hack at a later date, possibly after half a day of painstakingly trying to debug the code, not finding the real problem due to an obscure hack.